# How can I raise the "Wireless and Wired Network Settings" panel on Raspberry Pi from my application?

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi

**The Problem**

How can I raise the "Wireless and Wired Network Settings" panel on Raspberry Pi from my application?

**Details**

I am trying to create a GUI for embedded software on hardware driven by a Raspberry Pi 400. This system is designed to be used as a mobile appliance, not to give the user access to the Linux Desktop, so the embedded program runs in full screen mode. The one thing that it does need to be able to connect to different networks. I would like to embed the same functionality for changing and setting SSIDs and IP addresses that I can access from the wi-fi button in the top menu of the desktop, and embed a button that triggers the same behavior from within my application.

**Expected results**

I imagine there are some commands that I can send to the subprocess.run() which will raise either the list of WiFi networks to select between (left click in Desktop Wifi Menu) and the "Wired and Wireless Network Settings" window (right button click in Desktop Wifi Menu)

**What I have tried**

I have tried googling around for pages on "Wired and Wireless Network Settings" and network-manager on Raspberry Pi 400, but I have reached many complex pages on networking that don't address my specific problem.

***Can you help?***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I raise the "Wireless and Wired Network Settings" panel on Raspberry Pi from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794570/how-can-i-raise-the-wireless-and-wired-network-settings-panel-on-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score -2):

After some research I found some information that will be useful: the "Wired and Wireless Network Settings" in RPi OS is an LXDE panel applet:

https://wiki.lxde.org/en/How_to_write_plugins_for_LXPanel

so it is a library (`.so`), not a standalone executable.

You can find the lxplug-network applet source here:

https://github.com/raspberrypi-ui/lxplug-network